# Distribute a glade file inside an application

Tags: gtk3, gtkmm3

Before I start, I know of the existence of `GResource`, however I'm using gtkmm (C++), and I'm not sure if GResource works with C++. I can't find anything along the lines `Glib::GResource`, and I've been looking for a while.

Anyway, I'm writing a GUI using Gtkmm, and I want to pack the .glade file which I load within the executable, so that the executable can be run without having to have a file next to it. I'm not sure that I completely understand how GResources work, and I can't find any clear instructions anywhere.

So, using Gtkmm, how would I pack a .glade file inside my executable?

**update**: I've found [this.](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/unstable/classGio_1_1Resource.html) (Gio::Resource), which sounds hopeful, but no documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've made some more research and found [this tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-gio-resource.html.en) and [this documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/2.50/classGio_1_1Resource.html). Looks like what you need is `Gio::Resource::lookup_data_global`. Below is `C` version of my answer.

---

When something in glib world lacks documentation, it's time to read documentation for [c](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GResource.html). In short: with the help of [glib-compile-resources](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/glib-compile-resources.html) and a simple xml file you build a `.c` file, which can be compiled into your application. After that you can use `g_resources_lookup_data` (*resourceS*, it's important) to load data.

Comment: Thanks! From the second link you posted:
`Once a resource is registered the files in it can be accessed with the global resource lookup functions like g_resources_lookup_data().`.
That's talking about the function `void Gio::Resource::register_global()`. Do I, then, need to call this function before being able to use my resource?

Comment: Quote: _There are two forms of the generated source, the default version uses the compiler support for constructor and destructor functions (where available) to automatically create and register the Gio::Resource on startup or library load time. If you pass –manual-register, two functions to register/unregister the resource is instead created._

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. Seems like I won't have to call the register function myself then :)